# Joining 3 tables with multiples event associated to the same unique ID in each table with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-sql

I have three tables in Google Cloud SQL :

Event table :

```
id        Name     Date
A10117    foo      2017-01-01 0:00:00
A10617    bar      2017-01-06 0:00:00
A11017    barfoo   2017-01-10 0:00:00
A11317    foofoo   2017-01-13 0:00:00
A11417    barbar   2017-01-14 0:00:00
A12017    foobar   2017-01-20 0:00:00
```

Income table :

```
id        Income
A10117    1000
A10117    200
A10617    5000
A11017    3000
A11317    1500
A11317    560
A11417    2000
A12017    1500
```

Expenses table :

```
id        Expenses
A10117    80
A10617    25
A10617    75
A11017    99
A11317    123
A11317    45
A11417    34
A11417    95
A12017    678
```

I want the output to be one big table where each event is only one row with Income and Expenses properly sum.

for example in the final output I should have one row for ID A10617 :

```
id      Name   Date                  Income     Expenses
A10617  bar    2017-01-06 0:00:00    5000       100
etc...
```

I've built some query trying to consolidate all this using `WHERE` clause but I have some duplicate in my final output.

**So my question is :** How can I efficiently consolidate these 3 tables in one query ? My understand is I need to consolidate each table separately first one after another. I don't know how to do it.

My ideal query would be something like this :

```
SELECT id,Name,Date,sum(Income),sum(Expenses)
FROM Event e, Income i, Expenses ee
WHERE e.id = i.id = ee.id
GROUP BY id,Name,Date
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by joins ? and what query you have currently?

Comment: I want to be able to have one row by event with sum of Income and Expenses. Right I have independent query in separate sheet and then grouped in one master sheet .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select e.id, (select sum(Income) from income where id=e.id) as income, sum(ex.Income) as expenses from event as e inner join expenses as ex on e.id=ex.id group by e.id
```

This assumes all event ids are there in both income and expenses. If it is not the case change inner join to left join

Edit:
Little faster query:

```
select e.id, (select sum(Income) from income where id=e.id) as income, (select sum(Income) from expenses where id=e.id) as expenses from event as e
```

Comment: When applying this query event A10617 sum is not correct. Since there is two A10617 events in the Expenses table the sum of income for A10617 is 10000 when it should be 5000... I hope I'm clear.

Comment: I've already added the `group by e.id` when running the query. Otherwise the query didn't worked .

Comment: you also want to divide expenses by number of rows?
for a10617 : 75,25 are there. is result expected (75+25) or (75+25)/2

Comment: Result expected is (75+25)

Comment: check now @SimonBreton

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176080/discussion-between-shubham-singla-and-simon-breton).